# Segmentation fault when trying to read python process memory on Mac OS

Tags: python, c, macos, segmentation-fault, low-level

I was trying to figure out how the Mach VM Api works as there is almost 0 documentation around it and to do that I was messing around with reading/writing to other processes' memory.

To start I basically created a c program that constantly printed a string and its address. Then I used this program to try modifying the string mid execution and it worked fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#include <libproc.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_vm.h>

#define EXIT_ON_MACH_ERROR(msg, retval) \
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) { mach_error(msg ":" , kr); exit((retval)); }

uint32_t* get_pids(uint16_t* size) {
    // Gets all PIDS on the system to locate specific PID later. Probably inefficient
    // but I don't care

    uint32_t number_of_pids = proc_listpids(1, 0, NULL, 0);
    uint32_t* buffer = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t) * number_of_pids);
    uint8_t return_code = proc_listpids(1, 0, buffer, sizeof(buffer) * number_of_pids);
    uint16_t sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_pids; i++) {
        if(buffer[i] != 0) {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    uint32_t* final = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t) * sum);
    for(int i = 0, t = 0; i < number_of_pids; i++) {
        if(buffer[i]) {
            final[t++] = buffer[i];
        }
    }
    *size = sum;
    return final;
}
int main() {
    // Locate correct PID according to process name
    uint16_t size;
    uint32_t* pids = get_pids(&size);
    uint16_t maxpathlength = 1024;
    uint16_t path_size = maxpathlength * 4;
    char path_buffer[path_size];

    uint32_t process_pid = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        memset(path_buffer, '\0', sizeof(path_buffer));
        uint8_t return_code = proc_pidpath(pids[i], path_buffer, path_size);
        if(strstr(path_buffer, "Python")) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            process_pid = pids[i];
        }
        //printf("PID: %d, Process: %s\n", pids[i], path_buffer);

    }
    printf("%d\n", process_pid);
    struct proc_taskallinfo pro_info;
    uint32_t status = proc_pidinfo(process_pid, PROC_PIDTASKALLINFO, 0, &pro_info, sizeof(pro_info));
    
    printf("Python PID: %d\n", process_pid);
    printf("Self PID: %d\n", mach_host_self());
    mach_port_t port = 0;
    kern_return_t kr = task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), process_pid, &port);

    EXIT_ON_MACH_ERROR("task_for_pid", kr);
    printf("Port: %d\n\n\n", port);

    // STUFF
    mach_vm_address_t address = 0x102d4b770;
    mach_vm_address_t address_a = 0x102d4b770;

    char data[50] = "wow";
    vm_offset_t buf;
    mach_msg_type_number_t sz;

    // MEMORY DEALLOCATION

    kern_return_t suc = mach_vm_deallocate(port, (mach_vm_address_t) address, (mach_vm_size_t) 1000);
    if (suc!=KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("mach_vm_deallocate() failed with message %s!\n", mach_error_string(suc));
    }

    // MEMORY ALLOCATION
    kern_return_t all_suc = mach_vm_allocate(port, (mach_vm_address_t *) &address_a, (vm_size_t) 26, false);
    if (all_suc!=KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("mach_vm_allocate() failed with message %s!\n", mach_error_string(all_suc));
    }
    // WRITE TO MEMORY
    kern_return_t success = mach_vm_write(port, (vm_address_t) address, (vm_address_t)data, 26);
    if (success!=KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("mach_vm_write() failed with message %s!\n", mach_error_string(success));
    }
    
    // READ FROM MEMORY
    kern_return_t read_success = mach_vm_read(port, (vm_address_t) 0x6000018c4030, 26, &buf, &sz);
    if (read_success!=KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("mach_vm_read() failed with message %s!\n", mach_error_string(read_success));
    }
    char * newstr = (char *) buf;
    printf("%s\n", newstr);
    return 0;
}
```

`address` and `address_a` were entered manually after figuring out the variable's address. However, when I tried this with a python process where I again just constantly printed out the string and address, I got the following error message the instant I ran the code above:

`zsh: segmentation fault  python3 strtest.py`

I have no knowledge about CPython, so even after playing around a bit and trying to make it work, nothing happened. How can I make this work even on programs? I know its possible as [Bit-Slicer](https://github.com/zorgiepoo/Bit-Slicer) made it work but I wasn't able to found out how.

Comment: Messing around with another process's memory usually causes crashes.  Debuggers do it, but they are careful to ensure proper synchronization between the two processes.  Even reading another process's memory should be done carefully; you can run into problems.

Comment: Most systems use ASLR, so addresses will be different on a 2nd run.  Especially for dynamically-allocated memory.  Hard-coding an absolute address in CPython's address space might work for the same instance of the process, if the garbage collector hasn't moved it somewhere else.  (Also IIRC, (some?) Python objects are immutable, so assigning to a variable might allocate a new object and free the old one, rather than changing an object in-place.)

Comment: I did hard code the variable address from the same running process, and I also tried reading the memory but got nothing in return. What process do debuggers take for this?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. Basically, `hex(id(int))` gives the base address of the string struct however, since it's a struct, the actual string is located at a 48-byte offset.